# concurrency control in real time database

Tags: concurrency, databases

Can Lamport's Bakery algorithm be used for controlling concurrency in soft real time database system (case study of stock trading)?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems.

Comment: Currently, I'm doing a research on concurrency control on mixed soft real time database(case study of Stock Trading) an idea I got after reviewing much literatures. Since stock trading deadline sensitve, transaction isn't expected to conflict or miss deadline. Lots of approaches had been adopted in various works using either optimistic and pessimistic schemes. However, none of the researches utilized lamport's bakery algorithm in real time database. The quest to figure why led to my being member of this group, with the view of meeting experts  who could assist.